# align the child element middle inside the parent element

Tags: html, css

I am new to this. I need to align the circle in middle of the rectangle both vertical and horizontal.

**My CSS Code** :

```
.outerRectangle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
  }

  .innerCircle {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color:DodgerBlue;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;    
  }
```

```
<div>
    <rect class="outerRectangle">
       <circle class="innerCircle"></circle>
    </rect>   
</div>
```

**My output:**

[image]

**Expected :**

[image]

someone correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can help you.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

here use this, it will help!!!

```
.outerRectangle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `position absolute`

```css
.outerRectangle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }

  .innerCircle {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color:DodgerBlue;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <rect class="outerRectangle">
       <circle class="innerCircle"></circle>
    </rect>   
</div>
```

Here you go with a solution using `display: flex`

```css
.outerRectangle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center
  }

  .innerCircle {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color:DodgerBlue;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;    
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <rect class="outerRectangle">
       <circle class="innerCircle"></circle>
    </rect>   
</div>
```